# Celery put many tasks in the queue. Best practices

Tags: python, celery, task-queue, celery-task

I need to create a periodically script that put rows of a table into a task queue

for example:

```py
sa_engine = create_engine(...) # sqlalchemy engine
sql_query_to_select_new = text("SELECT TOP(30) FROM [my_table] WHERE [status] = 0")
sql_query_to_update = text("UPDATE [my_table] SET [status] = :new_status WHERE [status] = :prev_status and id = :id")
sql_query_to_select = text("UPDATE [my_table] SET [status] = 0 WHERE [status] = 1 AND id = :id")

@app.task
def my_task(row_id:int):
    with sa_engine.connect() as conn:
        my_row = conn.execute(sql_query_to_select, {'id': row_id}).first()

    # do something time consuming...
    
    with sa_engine.connect() as conn:
        conn.execute(sql_query_to_update, {"new_status": 2, "prev_status": 1, "id": row_id})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        with sa_engine.connect() as conn:
            row_ids = conn.execute(sql_query_to_select_new).all()
            for current_row in row_ids:
                my_task.apply_async(args=(current_row.id,))
                conn.execute(sql_query_to_update, {"new_status": 1, "prev_status": 0, "id": current_row.id})

        if not row_ids:
            sleep(30)
            continue
```

Is this the correct way? Does celery create a connection to the broker every time I call the apply_async?
Is there something like:

```py
with sa_engine.connect() as conn:
    with celery.some_function_returning_connection_pool() as broker_conn:
        row_ids = conn.execute(sql_query_to_select_new).all()
        for current_row in row_ids:
            broker_conn.apply_async(my_task, args=(current_row,))
            conn.execute(sql_query_to_update, {"new_status": 0, "prev_status": 1, "id": current_row.id})
```

I read the official celery documentation but didn't find what I was looking for.